# Dataset not found error while loading data from cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to GCP, I have my csv files kept in Cloud Storage Bucket. When I am trying to load them in my bigquery table from the console, I am receiving the below error:

Error:
Not found: Dataset Myproject1:Dataset1

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally occurs when your cloud storage bucket and bigquery dataset locations are different.

For example:
If your storage location is Asia and your bigquery dataset location is the United States(US), then you will end up getting this error. You have to keep your storage bucket location as well as your Bigquery dataset location the same.

You can refer to this documentation for more reference:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#data-locations